# Wifi connection issue in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, internet

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my Lenovo ThinkPad Laptop . Whenever I attempt to connect to my home Wi-Fi 'Authentication required' prompt appears. Even after providing my Wi-Fi password, it refuses to connect, and the prompt keeps reappearing. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.